# google docs api delete all content

Tags: google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I noticed from the [google docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate?apix_params=%7B%22documentId%22%3A%221ys6KIY1XOhPHrgQBJ4XxR1WDl0etZdmR9R48h2sP2cc%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22deleteContentRange%22%3A%7B%22range%22%3A%7B%22startIndex%22%3A1%2C%22endIndex%22%3A80%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D)

I can do

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "deleteContentRange": {
        "range": {
          "startIndex": 1,
          "endIndex": 80
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but if the endindex is greater than the total length of characters in the document, I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid requests[0].deleteContentRange: Index 79 must be less than the end index of the referenced segment, 7.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

but I just want to delete all of the content, even though I don't know the end range value.

So: is it possible to get the endIndex somehow, or delete all content another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to delete all contents in Google Document using Docs API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Issue:

In the current stage, in order to use "DeleteContentRangeRequest", both values of `startIndex` and `endIndex` are required. It seems that this is the specification. So in your case, I think that `is it possible to get the endIndex somehow, or delete all content another way?` leads to the method for resolving your issue.

### Flow of workaround:

Here, as the workaround, the following flow is used.

#### 1. Retrieve the object of `content` from Google Document.

The sample curl command is as follows. When you use this, please set the Document ID. In this case, `body.content(startIndex,endIndex)` is used as the fields. By this, it is easy to see the response value.

```
curl \
  'https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/###?fields=body.content(startIndex%2CendIndex)' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

The response value is like below.

```
{
  "body": {
    "content": [
      {"endIndex": 1},
      {"startIndex": 1, "endIndex": 100},
      {"startIndex": 100, "endIndex": 200}
    ]
  }
}
```

- `endIndex` of the last index of `content` is the value for this.

#### 2. Retrieve `endIndex` from the object.

From above response value, it is found that `startIndex` and `endIndex` are `1` and `199`, respectively. If `endIndex` is `200`, an error occurs. Please be careful this. So please reduce `1` from it.

#### 3. Delete all contents using `startIndex` and `endIndex`.

The sample curl command is as follows.

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/###:batchUpdate' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"requests":[{"deleteContentRange":{"range":{"startIndex":1,"endIndex":199}}}]}'
```

### References:

- [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)
- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [DeleteContentRangeRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#deletecontentrangerequest)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.